# Duas tabelas usando Where

Tags: php, sql-select

Tenho o ID de um usuário que esta em $usuario.

Tenho duas tabelas.

Tabela A (contém perguntas)

```
 coluna idA
 coluna perguntaA
```

Tabela B (armazena o id de uma pergunta respondida por um usuário)

```
 coluna idB
 coluna idusuarioB
```

1° O usuário entra em uma página X que mostra uma pergunta aleatória da Tabela A.

2° Quando ele responde, os dados dele e da pergunta são armazenados na Tabela B (idusuario = $usuario e idB = id da pergunta que ele respondeu).

3° Ele ao entrar na página X não verá mais aquela determinada pergunta. Ou seja, quero que meu select da página X não mostre uma pergunta já respondida pelo usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a clausula `no exists` ou `not in`:

```
select *
from  perguntas a
where 1 = 1 
  and not exists( select *
                   from perguntas_respondidas b
                   whre  1 = 1 
                     and b.id_pergunta  = a.id_pergunta
                     and b.id_aluno  = 12);
```

Comment: Carlos, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, um abraço meu amigo!

Comment: Luiz, eu fico feliz por ter contribuído. Abraço!